# Excel vba - how to declare string properly

Tags: excel, variable-declaration, vba

I've got some bits of code that is repeating itself many times, and I'm also using them on several "group-runs", so I'm re-using my code a lot. So, I'm trying to declare some values in such a way that I can change this only one time at the top of each run. 
Below I'm trying to declare a sheet name and a row number at the top, but I'm only getting a "variable not defined" error. Anyone that can help me how to declare these two values correct - and how to put them correct in to my code (other declarations is already done, and working).

```
Dim grsh, ntid As String
grsh = s1g1
ntid = 2289

Application.StatusBar = "Now updating: & grsh &   (new report data)."                   'grsh

        lr = sh_2_fravær.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        sh_2_fravær.Range("A3:E" & lr).ClearContents

            Set wb_Fravær = Workbooks("Fravær.xlsm")
            lr = wb_Fravær.Sheets("grsh").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row         'grsh
            wb_Fravær.Sheets("grsh").Range("A4:D" & lr).Copy                            'grsh

                sh_2_fravær.Range("A3").PasteSpecial
                Application.CutCopyMode = False



        lr = sh_11_tid.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        sh_11_tid.Range("A&ntid:L" & lr).ClearContents                                   'ntid

            Set wb_Tidsbruk = Workbooks("Tidsbruk.xlsm")
            lr = wb_Tidsbruk.Sheets("grsh").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row        'grsh
            wb_Tidsbruk.Sheets("grsh").Range("A5:I" & lr).Copy                           'grsh

                sh_11_tid.Range("A&ntid").PasteSpecial                                   'ntid
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: 1. `Dim grsh as string, ntid As Long` 2. `lr = wb_Fravær.Sheets(grsh).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` 3. `sh_11_tid.Range("A" & ntid & ":L" & lr).ClearContents` 4. `lr = wb_Tidsbruk.Sheets(grsh).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` 5. `wb_Tidsbruk.Sheets(grsh).Range("A5:I" & lr).Copy` 6. `sh_11_tid.Range("A" & ntid).PasteSpecial`

Comment: Also: `Application.StatusBar = "Now updating: "& grsh &  " (new report data)."`

Comment: Forgot `grsh = "s1g1"`

Comment: Updated my code, but I'm still getting a "Variable not defined" error, marking out line `grsh = s1g1` at the top.

Comment: With `grsh = "s1g1"`, it worked just fine! Thanks a lot for helping out.

Comment: @kit99, if you found the answer by jeeped helpfull you can let him know by clicking on the checkmark below the voting buttons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks primarily like basic syntax errors.

```
    Dim grsh As String, ntid As Long          '<~~ fixed
    grsh = "s1g1"                             '<~~ fixed
    ntid = 2289

    Application.StatusBar = "Now updating: " & grsh & " (new report data)."   '<~~ fixed

    lr = sh_2_fravær.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    sh_2_fravær.Range("A3:E" & lr).ClearContents

    Set wb_Fravær = Workbooks("Fravær.xlsm")
    lr = wb_Fravær.Worksheets(grsh).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row    '<~~ fixed
    wb_Fravær.Worksheets(grsh).Range("A4:D" & lr).Copy                       '<~~ fixed

    sh_2_fravær.Range("A3").PasteSpecial
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    lr = sh_11_tid.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    sh_11_tid.Range("A" & ntid & ":L" & lr).ClearContents                    '<~~ fixed

    Set wb_Tidsbruk = Workbooks("Tidsbruk.xlsm")
    lr = wb_Tidsbruk.Worksheets(grsh).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row   '<~~ fixed
    wb_Tidsbruk.Worksheets(grsh).Range("A5:I" & lr).Copy                      '<~~ fixed

    sh_11_tid.Range("A" & ntid).PasteSpecial                                  '<~~ fixed
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```